# AngularJS ng-repeat key-value pairs to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following HTML:

```
<p data-ng-repeat="(aName, aRating) in content.ratings">
    <div star-directive rating="aRating"></div>
</p>
```

aRating is an object.
The directive currently picks up "aRating" as a text for the rating variable.

What would the directive have to look like to be able to use the aRating object?

Comment: Can you send a plunker example of content.ratings and aRating? And what is rating doing with the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs.rating` is the expression string that you set to the attribute. You can evaluate it against the scope with `scope.$eval()`.

```
angular.module('your-module')
.directive('starDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var ratingExpression = attrs.rating;
      var rating = scope.$eval(attrs.rating);

      // Do something with rating.
    }
  }
});
```

`scope: false` is the default value, which means this directive does not create new scope and shares scope with its parent.

However, the above directive won't know when `aRating` is updated. If you want to update the directive as `aRating` changes, you can use isolate scope and data binding.

```
angular.module('your-module')
.directive('starDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      rating: '=rating'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      // `rating` object is available as `scope.rating` and it will keep updated.
    }
  }
});
```

This will create a new scope for the directive and bind `aRating` with the newly created scope's `rating` property. The new scope is **isolated** from the parent scope, which means it does not prototypically inherit from the parent scope. So it's a good toolkit for creating reusable components.

The `=` sign bidirectionally binds the `rating` attribute to the `rating` property of the directive's scope. That means that `scope.rating` will be updated when `aRating` changes and `aRating` will be updated when `scope.rating` changes.

If you are interested in isolate scope, see [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) for more details.